# T-SQL Use a variable as a table name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I am in the process of trying to condense several stored procedures in SSMS into a single one. All of the procedures were fairly similar in function: go through a table and change the value of a given field to a given variable. The only real differences between the procedures were the tables and fields referenced in them.

Based on other posts here on SO I came up with the following:

```
DECLARE @strQuery NVARCHAR(500)

SET @strQuery = 
    'UPDATE ' + @strTableName + 
    ' SET ' + @strField + ' = ' + @strNewFieldValue + 
    ' WHERE primaryKey = ' + CAST(@intNumber AS NVARCHAR(50));

EXECUTE @strQuery
```

However, when I try to run it I receive the following error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'UPDATE dbo.tableName SET dbo.Field = NewFieldValue WHERE pri

Which is the query I wanted to run with the last little bit truncated off. Changing the size of the `@strQuery`variable has no effect on the length of the error message. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sp_execute_sql`.  And parameters:

```
DECLARE @strQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @strQuery = '
UPDATE ' + strTableName + '
    SET ' + @strField + ' = @strNewFieldValue 
    WHERE primaryKey = @intNumber';

EXEC sp_executesql @strQuery,
                   N'@strNewFieldValue varchar(255), @intNumber int',
                   @strNewFieldValue=@strNewFieldValue, @intNumber=@intNumber;
```

Note that the literal values are replaced with parameters.  Even if SQL injection is not an issue, this simplifies the query and ensures that strange characters in the values do not unduly affect the query.

Also, SQL Server allows strings to span lines.  So I used that feature to remove some single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **sp_executesql** instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EXECUTE (@strQuery)
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and note the parenthesis in the syntax for "Execute a character string". Without the parenthesis, SQL Server thinks you want to execute a stored procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding parenthesis didn't work for me